# Fullcalendar date issue

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, fullcalendar

I'm using Fullcalendar, and have created a list of events (that are draggable).

When dropping in an event the drop method get's called.

```
drop: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, ui) {
    console.log(date.getDay());
    console.log(date);
```

The output of this is:

```
3 
Wed Jan 02 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

While I expected the first line to output 2 or 02.

The allDay param is false, because I'm always dropping in the month calendar view.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a FullCalendar problem, but an RTD one. [`Date.getDay()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) returns the day of the week, from `0` to `6` (Sunday through Saturday). Wednesday is `3`.

Use [`Date.getDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) to get the day of the month (`1` to `31`).